# JPA / Hibernate delete entity from association table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I have the following hibernate mappings:

Class `Folders`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOLDER")
public class Folders implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "folder_seq")
    @Column(name = "ID_FOL")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "NOFOLDER")
    private String noFolder;
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "M_DOMAIN_DN", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "FK_FOLDER", referencedColumnName = "ID_FOL") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_DOMAIN", referencedColumnName = "ID_DOM") })
    private List<Domain> domain = new ArrayList<Domain>();
    /**  GETTER + SETTER **/

}
```

Class `Domain` :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOMAIN")
public class Domain {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "domain_seq")
    @Column(name = "ID_DOM")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;
    @Column(name = "LABEL")
    private String label;
    public Long getId() {
        /**  GETTER + SETTER **/
}
```

Method that deletes an entity of type `Folder`:

```
public void deleteFolder(Long id) {
    try {
        entityManager.remove(getFolderById(id));
        entityManager.flush();
    } catch (PersistenceException e) {

    }
}
```

I tried to delete the entity `Folder` but is not deleted in the database. Deleting manually in the database works fine, looking for help trying to solve this issue.

Comment: you're ignoring the exception which is the most important part in your code, as it tells you what is happening. Please provide the stack trace

Comment: There is not exception with this ... just after execute method the entities is not removed in database ..

Comment: Add e.printStackTrace() inside the catch:
    try {
        entityManager.remove(getFolderById(id));
        entityManager.flush();
    } catch (PersistenceException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
    }
And tell us what appears in the console, or use the logger of your choice

Comment: Yes I tried it, but it amazing because it's not entered in the catch block and in console I have nothing to appear

Comment: Change PersistenceException to Exception then. Have you other working code? You don't seem to start a transaction anywhere nor commit. Could also be that your getFolderById does not return the actual Folder

Comment: Yes I have a code who works fine like the remove of entity `Domain ` worked fine, and `getFolderById ` return the folder that I want to delete .. i don't know but maybe my annotation is not corrected ? I forgot to add something for deleting cascade ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153673/discussion-between-mario-fernandes-and-user1814879).

Comment: Check your delete method is called with in transaction.